# Some of my rails migration files missing in release folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano

Previously i had deleted some migration files,which caused missing relations error(while tying to deploy to new server) so to fix that i added back the deleted migration files.I committed and pushed the new changes to gitlab after which i tried cap production deploy and still getting the **missing relation error** .On checking he release folder in the server i found that newly added back migrations files were not present.How to fix this.

I thought of trying to manually create the files in server,but cap production deploy is creating new release folders each time

how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by executing  the following commands inside server release folder

1)
I ran

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:reset DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 --trace`

2) `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:setup DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1`

3)After this i executed `cap production deploy` and it all seems good

Note1: try executing the above commands  first without `DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 --trace`  if prompted add this command

Note2: In case u had some migration files deleted and currently u are trying to deploy to new server,then even if `cap production deploy` fails with missing relation error(caused by deleted migrations) you can get inside the latest release folder and run above commands to get the database setup correctly,after which u can try `cap production deploy` which most probably wont show any issues(related to deleted migration files)